# Will adhoc iOS app work after revoking it's signing certificate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I had created an iOS app earlier for **Adhoc** development.I used a provisioning profile with some certificate.But now accidentally revoked the certificate by which i signed my app.Now I have released for **Adhoc** development so will user able to install that **IPA** file which was generated earlier or do i need to again generate a new **IPA** file with new certificate?

Answer (score 1):

User can install ipa file which was generated earlier my friend. If you create new ipa than you need to generate a new IPA file with new certificate.

Comment: Thanks it means if i try to generate a new IPA file with previous revoked certificate then it won't work but the earlier IPA file will work just fine although the certificate is revoked for previous IPA file. right?